# ChangeNotifierProvider between different pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I've been searched but I didn't find any question (sorry If I there is some yet...)
My question is:
I have two pages, I use ChangeNotifierProvider in this two pages, but when I change a value in the second page and go back to the first page, the widget does not refresh with the new value.
The code:

**main.dart:**

```
Future main() async {
  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<NewsModel>(create: (context) => NewsModel()),
          // Other providers...
        ],

        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'App',
          home: FirstPage(),
          routes: pageRoutes.getRoutes(context))
    );
  }
}
```

***first_page.dart:***

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FirstPageState();

}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    NewsModel model = Provider.of<NewsModel>(context, listen:true);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("First page")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Recent news: ${model.recentNews.length}"),
                    FlatButton(
                       onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, pageRoutes.second_page),
                       child: Text("Go to Second Page to clear recents")
                    );
                    // If clear recents from here works well (text is updated to 0 after clear)
                    FlatButton(
                       onPressed: ()=>model.clear(),
                       child: Text("Clear recents from First Page")
                    );
                ]))));
  }

}
```

***second_page.dart:***

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SecondPageState();

}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    NewsModel model = Provider.of<NewsModel>(context, listen:true);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second Page page")),
      body: Center(child:                     
         FlatButton(
            // When press the button and go back to first page, text is not updated... why??
            onPressed: () {
                model.clear();
                Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text("Clear recents")
         )));
  }

}
```

***provider.dart:***

```
class NewsModel with ChangeNotifier {

  //@ Some random news ids
  List<dynamic> _recentNews = [2543, 125, 288];

  List<dynamic> get recentNews => _recentNews;

  set recentNews(List<dynamic> value) { 
    _recentNews=value; 
     notifyListeners(); 
  }

   void clear() {
    _recentNews.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Thank you very much to all!!

Comment: If I run the code it works perfectly fine (just changed the named route to a MaterialPageRout to make it compile)

Comment: No works in my case, but thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You must use the same object in the two pages.
Learn about ChangeNotifierProvider.value named constructor.